# Where is Spark writing SaveAsTextFile in cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a bit at loss here (Spark newbie). I spun up an EC2 cluster, and submitted a Spark job which saves as text file in the last step. The code reads

```
reduce_tuples.saveAsTextFile('september_2015')
```

and the working directory of the python file I'm submitting is /root. I cannot find the directory called september_2005, and if I try to run the job again I get the error:

```
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://ec2-54-172-88-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/user/root/september_2015 already exists
```

The ec2 address is the master node where I'm ssh'ing to, but I don't have a folder */user/root*.

Seems like Spark is creating the september_2015 directory somehwere, but *find* doesn't find it. Where does Spark write the resulting directory? Why is it pointing me to a directory that doesn't exist in the master node filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not saving it in the local file system, you're saving it in the hdfs cluster. Try `eph*-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -ls /`, then you should see your file. See `eph*-hdfs/bin/hadoop help` for more commands, eg. `-copyToLocal`.

Comment: Thanks @Reactormonk! I can see the folder now, I can see now that I can use `ephemeral-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/root/september_2015 /root/` to copy the folder to my master node.